# Use 'having' over a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to get the name of the  servers that have the maxium number of clients. I tried to count the number of clients for each server and the use having to filter but it is not working:

```
SELECT s.id FROM (
SELECT s.id,COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Server s
JOIN Client v ON s.id = c.idServer
GROUP BY s.id)T 
HAVING Total = MAX(Total);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES s.id, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Server s JOIN
     Client v
     ON s.id = c.idServer
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```